# NSUserDefaults not saved when cache/memory clears

Tags: ios, caching, ios7, nsuserdefaults

i am using `NSUserDefaults` to save a string in my app. It all works fine. But when i clear the cache/memory by pressing the homebutton twice, kill the app and restart it again the `NSUserDefaults` is not saved.

Is there a way to save the `NSUserDefaults` even when i clear cache/memory?

Here is the code i use:

**To set the string**

```
NSUserDefaults *savedString = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[savedString setObject:@"The string i want to save" forKey:@"savedString"];
[savedString synchronize];
```

**To get the string**

```
myLabel.text = [savedString stringForKey:@"savedString"];
```

Comment: Did you synchronised that userDefaults ?

Comment: Yes i did use synchronised.

Comment: If you remove app then only `NSUserDefault` will remove all data.

Comment: Did you remove the app from device/simulator ?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: You're probably not saving the data in the right place. I recommend you check when you're saving your data.

Comment: You have Not Code properly code. I am also use my below code for session maintain. and i delete apps it also work fine.

Comment: I am not removing my app. I just clear the cache/memory by pressing the home button twice and the swipe the app up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.h file

```
+(NSUserDefaults*)getdefaultvalue;
```

In Your AppDelegate.m file

```
static NSUserDefaults *defaultvalue;

+(NSUserDefaults*)getdefaultvalue
{
    if (defaultvalue==nil)
    {
        defaultvalue=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        return defaultvalue;
    }
    return  defaultvalue;

}
```

In your class where you want to save data or string Ex.

```
[[AppDelegate getdefaultvalue] setObject:@"FacebookLogin" forKey:@"NORMALOGIN"];
```

Now Remove from apps and print the value of string in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  NSLog(@" string == %@",[[AppDelegate getdefaultvalue] valueForKey:@"NORMALOGIN"]);

  Return YES;

}
```

You got String value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually NSUserDefault save data in .plist, So when you remove you app then all data also get deleted.

Comment: He didn't say he completely deleted the app, he just killed it.

Answer (score -2):

Deleting the app will delete the plist file the `NSUserDefaults` generate. You will need to make a check if the files exists in your app, then load the `UserDefaults` if not, create the plist with the information. So you will have your standard settings when the user opens the app etc.